# Can we use canonical name to filter Computers?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I ran a command to get Computers in an OU filtering canonical name rather using searchbase. I got error:

> “A filter was used that uses constructed attributes”

What's that?

I think it's because canonicalname is not one of those properties we see by default when we search for computer like Name, DN, etc. It's something you have explicitly mention in properties to get value. That's a wild guess.
Image attached for reference.

[image]

Comment: I'd try to enclose the `-Filter` parameter in "double quotes" instead of a {script block}

Comment: I have been using curly brackets ... any reason why use double quotes rather script block

Comment: I'm not in an AD environment ATM so can't test myself, but remember sevaral hints of users mklement0/AnsgarWiechers in [SO] advising not to use a script block for -Filters. Did you try it?

Comment: @LotPings  - Just now tried and it didn't work .. same error .. Just an FYI,  I wrote : Get-ADComputer -filter "canonicalname  -like  '**WorkstationsWin10/Test/W10MigrationTest/Laptop**'"  -Properties * | select canonicalname

Comment: Can you explain what you believe you gain my using this property?
Also, you are asking for all properties, then only select one. It's more prudent to only select the one you want. Eliminate the extra step (code).

Comment: I wanted to get list of all machines in same location of which 1 I know. Didnt wanted to use console and the ou path was too lengthy to remember, so was copying canonical name from 1st machine and useing that as wild card getting list of all machines in same location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not real sure of a use case where one should need to use this property, this way, vs the more commonly use properties, yet, the simple answer is nope.

Of course, there is always...

```
Clear-Host
Get-ADComputer -Filter '*' -Properties CanonicalName  | 
Where {$($PSitem.CanonicalName) -eq 'contoso.com/Computers/WS01'} | 
Select-Object -Property CanonicalName
```

Or

```
(Get-ADComputer -Filter '*' -Properties CanonicalName  | 
Where {$($PSitem.CanonicalName) -eq 'contoso.com/Computers/WS01'}).CanonicalName
```

Comment: Thnx it worked. FYI i tried to up vote it and it failed because my level iis too low apparently !!

Comment: No worries, glad it was useful. As for the upvote, yep, that is a thing,  but since you are the OP, you can accept it as your answer.